# Linux Event Polling not working when using thread

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, linux-device-driver

I have the following code to pool event data (based on this [Multitouch Protocol](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt)). In order to do so without delay to my application I decided to use threading. The problem is the thread get stuck in the line where it contains:
**read(_touchEvent, &ie, sizeof(ie));**

I tried putting printf statements around it and its printing prior to it but not after it.

```
void TouchDriverAdapter::_poolData(){
  // Refer to kernel multitouch.
  struct input_event ie;
  read(_touchEvent, &ie, sizeof(ie));
  if(ie.code == ABS_MT_SLOT){
    _currentSlot = ie.value;
  }else if(ie.code == SYN_REPORT){
    _numContacts = _currentSlot;
    // Transfer cached data to vector.
    for(int i = 0; i <= _numContacts; i++){
      _touchData[i] = _touchDataTemp[i];
    }
  }else{
    if(ie.code == ABS_X){   
      _touchDataTemp[_currentSlot].x = ie.value;
      printf("%i\n", ie.value);
    }else if(ie.code == ABS_Y){
      _touchDataTemp[_currentSlot].y = ie.value;
    }
  }

  _lastCode = ie.code;
}
```

Heres the singleton that i have that creates the thread.

```
// Singleton.
TouchDriverAdapter* TouchDriverAdapter::getInstance(){
  if(_instance->_touchEvent < 0){
    return NULL;
  }else if(_running == false){
    int result = pthread_create( TouchDriverAdapter::_thread, NULL, 
                 TouchDriverAdapter::_runThread, 
                 (void*)&_instance);
    if(result != 0){
      printf("Error: %i, Failed to create a thread.\n", result);
      return NULL;
    }
    _running = true;
    pthread_detach( *TouchDriverAdapter::_thread);
    //pthread_join( *TouchDriverAdapter::_thread, NULL);
    return TouchDriverAdapter::_instance;
  }else if(_running == true){
    return _instance;
  }
}
```

Again this works when I dont use threading but I can only read segments of data at a time which is kinda useless for multi-touch application.

Comment: You should try to poll with the [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) syscall!!

Comment: And you should test the result of [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) ...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I read the documentation about [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) but if I'm not mistaken it's only so you dont waste computing power in a while loop, read already implement such functionality though.

Comment: No, `poll` will tell you if a file descriptor is *readable*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using POSIX pthread_t above, a library not written with classes in mind. The C++'s std::thread on the other hand made this event polling work flawlessly, I just have to add -std=c++11.